# double integration with enclosed region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I recentely solved a question on multiple Integration and i have encountered a question like this

Finding

> $$\int_{\text{E}}\frac{y}{x}d(x,y)$$
>
> Where $E$ is bounded by the curve $x^2-y^2=1,x^2-y^2=4$ and $y=0$ to $\displaystyle y=\frac{x}{2}$

I did not understand the meaning of that integral notation.

Is this represent the double integration and we can represent like this way

$$\int^{\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}}_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}\int^{\frac{x}{2}}_{0}\frac{y}{x}dydx+\int^{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}_{-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}}\int^{0}_{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{y}{x}dydx$$
Help me please , thanks

Graph

[image]

Comment: You are correct in interpreting that the notation most likely meant a double integral. However, draw your region. You will see that it should be two integrals in either direction.

Comment: Your bounds are still very off base. Draw a picture of the region.

Comment: Actually i interpreate along $x$ axis and take $=2/\sqrt{3}$ to $x=4/\sqrt{3}.$ and $y=0$ to $y=x/2$  while drawing picture.

Comment: you are not drawing the other curves $x^2-y^2 = 1$ and $x^2-y^2=4$. Excluding them is a silly thing to do.

Comment: Above have draw graph. Can you please tell me what should be the limit of $x$ and $y$.Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Now I clearly understand where you see the symmetry. I interpreted the statement $y=0$ $\textbf{to}$ $y=x/2$ to mean that $0\leq y \leq x/2$ because of the use of the word "to" (which would imply the direction in the inequalities), which would exclude the left region, but that is not to say that that couldn't be an interpretation. Only the source of this problem could clear up that miscommunication.

Comment: To address your other concerns, look at the right region. If I go straight up, do I always have the same top and bottom bounds? (The answer is no, it must be split into $3$ integrals). If I go straight horizontally, do I always have the same left and right bounds? (Again, the answer is no, it will be $2$ integrals this way)

Comment: For left side $y$ varies from $x/2$ to $0$ and $x$ varies from $-4//sqrt{3}$ to $-2/sqrt{3}$ and for right $y$ varies from $0$ to $x/2$ and $x$ from $2/sqrt{3}$ to $4/sqrt{3}$

Comment: Not true, you are ignoring the little side pieces that get missed if you do that integral. My advice to you, ask desmos to plot the vertical lines $x = 2/\sqrt{3}$ and $x = 4/\sqrt{3}$ and tell me how many regions does it split the integral into.

Comment: It is to complex from $x,y$ coordinate . I have seems that your polar coordinate method is fine.

Comment: I am glad you have reached that conclusion, but I would like you to answer my questions just so I can make sure you understand. Do you see how many regions the integral gets split into when you do $dy$ then $dx$ ? Do you see the problem with the way you have the integral set up currently?

Comment: You got an answer out of me, the least you could do is give me something I want, which is to know that you understood something better than from before you posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to a "hyperbolic" coordinates inspired by polar coordinates:

$$\begin{cases} x = k\cosh t \\ y = k\sinh t \\ \end{cases} \implies J = k$$

The equations of the boundaries in the new coordinate system become

$$\begin{cases} x^2-y^2 = 1 \\ x^2-y^2 = 4 \\ y = 0 \\ y = \frac{x}{2} \\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}k = 1 \\ k = 2 \\ t = 0 \\ t = \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ \end{cases}$$

giving us the integral

$$\int_0^{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) } \int_1^2 \tanh(t) k\:dk\:dt = \frac{3}{2}\log\left(\cosh(t)\right)\Bigr|_0^{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} = \frac{3}{4}\log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Here we multiply it by $2$. Is i am right @Ninad Munshi. Because total enclosed area is $2$ times of that definite Integration. Also i am jot getting $\ln$ terms. Plesse explain me

Comment: @jacky why do we multiply it by $2$ ? I don't see a reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks Ninad. I interpreate it as total area. But my answer is not comming in $\ln$ form please clearfy me.

Comment: @jacky your interpretation of total area is correct, but you must be drawing the picture incorrectly if you see a symmetry. The region and the integrand do not have any such symmetry here. Second, I can't answer why you are not getting $\log$ because I don't see your work. I can only tell you to read what I did. Everything follows from first calculus principles.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ u=x^2-y^2,v=\frac{y}{x} ,dxdy=\frac{1}{2-2v^2}dudv $
$$ I=\int_{1}^{4}du \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{v}{2-2v^2}dv=\frac{3}{4}\ln(\frac{4}{3}) $$

Comment: Can you please eleborate more about This . Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand How you calculate $\displaystyle dxdy=\frac{1}{2-2v^2}dudv.$ @ Eeyore Ho.

Comment: The selection of u and v in the substitution formula is usually determined by the characteristics of the integrand or the shape of the integral region.

Comment: Do you know the Jacobi determinant？

Comment: Yes Eeyore i have a little knowledge.

Comment: $ \iint_{D}f(x,y) dxdy=\iint_{D^{'}}f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\left |J(u,v) \right | dudv $